# Qt: More versatile alternatives of QRubberBand?

Tags: c++, qt

I've already managed to draw a QRubberBand of rectangular shape, but is it possible to draw a QRubberBand of any shape if the user wants? Like, if the user likes it to shape the rubberband very much like a circle is it possible to do so with QRubberband, if not, is there an alternative option that is more versatile than QRubberBand? Also, the way we can get the coordinate or location of QRubberBand, is it possible to get the same from the alternative option too?

Thanks.

Comment: As dosc say: "The QRubberBand class provides a **rectangle or line** that can indicate a selection or a boundary.", I conclude that there is no built-in way to change the shape.

Comment: Probably you can subclass QRubberband and override the methods for thea boundaries and shape.

Comment: `QRubberBand` is just a wrapper over some function in whatever style your app uses. Usually the style just draws a rect with some pattern placed into it. Do the same yourself for more versatility. Check qt source code for more details.